# Ef6 Web api 2 angularjs open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have an angularjs function that issue two rest requests to my web api 2 back end, one to get list of classes, another one for a drop down of course. I get an error from time to time:-

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

I wouldn't want to turn on the on the 'MultipleActiveResultSets=true;', is there any solution for this?

Here are my code:-

js file

```
$scope.init = function () { 
    $scope.getClasses();
    $scope.getCourseIdAnValue('test');
};
```

Web api back end:-

ClassController.cs > getClasses function

```
    List<ClassDTO> list;
            using (var dataContext = MyContext())
            {
                list = dataContext.Classes
                .Include(x => x.Course)
                .Include(x => x.Tutor)
                .Project().To<ClassDTO>()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Course.Value).ThenBy(x => x.ClassName)
                .Select(x => x).ToList();
            }

            return list;
```

CourseController.cs > getCourseIdAnValue function

```
    List<CourseIdAndValue> list;
        using (var dataContext = MyContext())
        {
            var query = dataContext.Courses.AsQueryable();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
                query = query.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(keyword));

            list = query.Project().To<CourseIdAndValue>()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                .Select(x => x).ToList();
        }

        return list;
```

Comment: Can you explain why don't you want to turn on `MultipleActiveResultSets`?

Comment: Can you swap the order of  calls for your backend.